# Tkinter key press trigger event

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Hi Im trying to run a function based on input from user, what am I doing wrong?

If i do

```
def onKeyPress(input = 1 | 2):
    playSound
```

it works fine if i press 1 or 2

but if i do

```
def onKeyPress(input = 1 | 2):
    if input == 1:
        command = playSound()
    elif input == 2:
        command = nextFile()
```

I get nothing if i press 1 or 2, nothing happens. I assume im not checking if input is 1 or 2 properly? Thanks

Comment: What do you think `input = 1 | 2` is doing, exactly? It just makes the default value `3`, it's not testing anything.

Comment: I normally program in c++ so python is foreign to me i thought it meant 'or' as in c++ || is or

Comment: Yes, it's a bitwise or, but why not just set `input=3`?

Comment: I was checking if input is 1 or 2. if i wanted to add 1 and 2 i would just use + or as you said input = 3. The answer by falstru solved my problem though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event handler (or callback function) will be called with an Event object, not with an integer. The event object will never be equal to `int` object.

If you check specific key is pressed, use `char`, `keysym` or `keycode` attribute of the event passed:

```
def onKeyPress(event):
    if event.char == '1':  # OR  event.keycode == 49:
        playSound()
    elif event.char == '2':  # OR  event.keycode == 50:
        nextFile()
```